# React Native - Animated ScrollView set opacity on scroll

Tags: react-native, animation, scrollview

i tried to use the contentOffset.y to interpolate the opacity of the scrollView items in vertical mode, like the horizontal example below.

example (vertical) : https://snack.expo.io/@doooooo0ooo/scrollview-vertical-opacity-animation
example (horizontal) : https://snack.expo.io/@doooooo0ooo/scrollview-horizontal-opacity-animation

I tried different interpolation value in input and output but nothing seem to work.
I don't understand what's the difference between those axis in term of animation.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for people who try to do the same thing... i tried to use codesandbox, because i didn't understand the issue... why it was not possible to use the y axis for animation... and then... with the same logic, the animation is done.

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-animated-scrollview-nn1g9